# Plotly-Geo Chloropleth not working on Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, plotly, data-visualization, geopandas

so I am trying to plot something over counties in California and I'm using the code below. Somehow, it's throwing an error saying:

```
Run the following commands to install the correct versions of the following modules:


    $ pip install geopandas==0.3.0
    $ pip install pyshp==1.2.10
    $ pip install shapely==1.6.3

    If you are using Windows, follow this post to properly install geopandas and dependencies:http://geoffboeing.com/2014/09/using-geopandas-windows/

    If you are using Anaconda, do not use PIP to install the packages above. Instead use conda to install them:


    $ conda install plotly
    $ conda install geopandas
```

Since I'm using Anaconda I did conda download and did pip install separately for pyshp and shapely. Thus, all my imports are working fine. I don't know why I'm still getting this error. Earlier I was in a different environment on Anaconda but am now working in the base environment. All my libraries seem to be in lpace but I'm still getting this error.

My code:

```
import geopandas
import shapely
from plotly.figure_factory._county_choropleth import create_choropleth
import plotly

counties = cal_fips['countyFIPS'].tolist()
numbers = cal_fips[cal_fips['variable'] == '4/18/20']['value'].tolist()

endpt = np.linspace(0,15000,num=30)

fig = create_choropleth(fips=counties, values=numbers, colorscale=px.colors.sequential.Reds, show_state_data=True, binning_endpoints=endpt, county_outline={'color': 'rgb(255,255,255)', 'width': 0.5}, legend_title='% change', title='% Change in disease between 1980-2014')

fig.layout.template = None
fig.show()
```

Comment: create a new conda environment, re-install everything from the conda-forge channel

Comment: Okay I see, seems like a mammoth task XD. Do you think there's any other way to create the plots without figure factory maybe?